# Printing on a Rasperry Pi with CUPS and a Brother MFC

Tags: raspberry-pi, cups, brother

I have installed a Brother MFC Printer (DCP-9055CDN) on a Rasperry Pi 400. Printing works but there is always an additional page with one single line printed 'Box86 with Dynarec v.0.2.1 aa7b620d built on Apr 7 2021 17:38:04).

What can I do to suppress this additional page?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Brother do not provide an ARM binary for the Raspberry Pi architecture, so their Intel x86 binary is used instead, with an emulator **Box86** to run it. The message you see is presumably from this emulator, as we can see in the sources of [build_info.c](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/blob/master/src/build_info.c):

```
void PrintBox86Version()
{
    printf("Box86%s%s v%d.%d.%d %s built on %s %s\n",
```

Looking at where this is called in [main.c](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/blob/master/src/main.c) we see it depends on C variable `box86_nobanner` and this is set from a `getenv()`. More simply, the help output says we can set:

> BOX86_NOBANNER with 0/1 to enable/disable the printing of box86 version and build at start

You need to look through the files you installed to see where you can set `BOX86_NOBANNER=1` in the CUPS environment. (I can't do that at the moment).

As a simple quick alternative, if you have a binary file `/usr/bin/box86`, you could rename it and put a shell script in its place setting this variable then calling the renamed binary repeating the parameters.